# Can you paint over an existing image texture in Texture Paint?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm thinking of painting over my current image texture to fix a few errors instead of going back to my image editor and make a guess work on corrections. Is that possible?

And if I'm to duplicate an existing texture paint image, will the original be affected by the edits I'll make on the duplicate? If yes, how can I make a independent duplicate just so I can go back to the original if I didn't like the edit.

Answer (score 0):

ok...yes is possible, but I don't know where to duplicate it in the texture painting panel, but in the shader...
first add your texture with image texture
[image]

second: duplicate image texture with shift + d ... and click in the number next to name
[image]

and ready select one and edit

or you can save copy,and open your original texture again.

Comment: Nice. Thank you, I'll try that :)